# Creating this shape (Attached picture) in Android XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, shapes

I know this question is very brief but how can I create this shape in XML for an Android Studio project?

[image]

It seems like I can create a rectangle and then remove a semi circle portion from it but achieving that effect in XML seems very difficult. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: `"but achieving that effect in XML seems very difficult:"`, yes, i agree, you can either use a nine patch drawable or `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create such background with pure `xml` drawables is always tricky, but possible.

I've created button you need in `xml`. Add this files to your `drawable` folder:

**circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <!-- inset - moves circle to the left-->
        <inset android:insetLeft="-150dp">
            <shape android:shape="ring"
                    android:thicknessRatio="7"
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:useLevel="false"
                    >
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
                <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**custom_button_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00ff00"/>
            <stroke
                    android:color="#000000"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
</layer-list>
```

**custom_button_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#dddddd"/>
            <stroke
                    android:color="#000000"
                    android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />

</layer-list>
```

**custom_button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button_default"/>
</selector>
```

Set `custom_button_selector` drawable as a background of your view in `layout`:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_selector"
        />
```

You probably will have to adjust circle `insetLeft` value and button `width`, `height` in `layout`. Would be better to have this variables defined in `values/dimens.xml`.

**Default state:**

[image: Default state]

**Pressed state:**

[image: Pressed state]

I've tested it on Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 - button background looks the same.

Comment: Nice! Be careful with testing on Nexus devices, though. They always work correctly :P The only problem with this is that the background cannot be transparent. It must be of a solid color.

Comment: Yes, you're right, achieving transparency for a circle part is a bit harder. And I'm testing everything on Samsung devices after I finish a task, to make sure it works on non-Nexus devices too :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you ca use convert online tools http://www.online-convert.com/ after convert svg to xml android file this site http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/